# Add bracket around a string that match this pattern

Tags: unix, sed

**Using sed commands**

In the following sentence add [] around words starting with s and containing e and t in any
order “subtle exhibit asset sets tests site”.

Here is what I have so far (see code section)

```
$ echo "subtle exhibit asset sets tests site." | sed 's/^s\ "et"/[]/g'
```

Comment: Use `&` in the replacement string to copy the matched string.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around `et`?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the line. So your regexp will only match the first word in a line. Why do you have that?

Comment: Why do you have `\ ` after the `s`? You don't want to match spaces, you want to match words.

Comment: There's practically nothing in that regexp that seems to be doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for, using GNU sed for `-E` so we don't need to escape the `(` and `)` capture group delimiters and can use `|` for "or", and `\w` shorthand for word-constituent characters and `\<` word boundary:

```
$ echo 'subtle exhibit asset sets tests site.' |
    sed -E 's/\<s\w*(e\w*t|t\w*e)\w*/[&]/g'
[subtle] exhibit asset [sets] tests [site].
```